# InputMismatchException when using an input Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am writing a program that reads through a file of various types of data.  I am trying pass in the data from the file, to various arrays that I have created.

Sample portion from file (double spaced for line breaks.  White spaces between categories are tabs, but white space between first/last names and countries are spaces)

```
Name Age    Country Year    Closing Date    Sport   Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total

Joe Max 24  Algeria 2012    8/12/2012   Athletics   1   0   0   1

Tom Lan 27  United States   2008    8/24/2008   Rowing  0   1   0   1
```

When my code compiles, however, I get the InputMismatchException. I am wondering if it deals with the fact that at the end of each line, there is no tab that ensues.  Can anyone help me through this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
intro();

Scanner input1 = null;
Scanner input2 = null;
int lineCount = 0;

try {
    input1 = new Scanner(new File("olympicstest.txt"));

} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Option");
    System.exit(1);
}

while (input1.hasNextLine()) {
    lineCount++;
    input1.nextLine();
}

lineCount = lineCount - 1;

String[] country = new String[lineCount];
int[] totalMedals = new int[lineCount];
String[] name = new String[lineCount];
int[] age = new int[lineCount];
int[] year = new int[lineCount];
String[] sport = new String[lineCount];

try {
    input2 = new Scanner(new File("olympicstest.txt"));
    input2.useDelimiter("\t");  
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Option");  // not sure if this line is needed
    System.exit(1);  // not sure if this line is needed
}        

String lineDiscard = input2.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
    name[i] = input2.next();
    age[i] = input2.nextInt();
    country[i] = input2.next();
    year[i] = input2.nextInt();
    input2.next();  // closing ceremony date
    sport[i] = input2.next(); 
    input2.nextInt();  // gold medals
    input2.nextInt();  // silver medals
    input2.nextInt();  // bronze medals
    totalMedals[i] = input2.nextInt();
}

}
```

Comment: You say it's your output, don't you mean that input?

Comment: You are correct.  It should read input.  Fixing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes when you set a specific delimiter, unfortunately that becomes the only delimiter used to separate values which don't play nicely with your `.next()` statements, so you can either add tabs (`\t`) to the end of each line or you can set both `\t` and `\n` to delimiters with regex `"[\t\n]"`.  I also prefer to use CSV format, and separate all values with commas because tabs and whitespace characters often aren't very distinguishable from a visual standpoint so I've found it is easier to use/format later on

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right about what's causing the problem. A solution would be to use a regex in the `useDelimiter` call that accepts both tabs and linebreaks. So you would do:

```
input2.useDelimiter("[\t\n]");
```

[Explanation of the regex](http://regex101.com/r/rQ0lI1)